# mysql on freebsd makes 1GB binary log files every 20 minutes filling free disk space very fast

Tags: mysql, freebsd, log-files

I have a problem with MySQL on FreeBSD.

It makes a lot of 1GB binary files every 20 minutes and it's filling free disk space rapidly.

```
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1073741982 2013-09-14 18:26 mysql-bin.000174
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1073741890 2013-09-14 18:42 mysql-bin.000175
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1073741988 2013-09-14 18:59 mysql-bin.000176
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1073741964 2013-09-14 19:15 mysql-bin.000177
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1073741974 2013-09-14 19:29 mysql-bin.000178
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1073741923 2013-09-14 19:46 mysql-bin.000179
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  577143852 2013-09-14 19:59 mysql-bin.000180
```

It happens without any internet activity from users. I have `max_binlog_file=526870912` in my.cnf

I tried to do

```
freebsd# mysql -u root -p
mysql> flush logs;
mysql> flush master;
```

All mysql-bin files is deleted as a result and counting starts from mysql-bin.000001.

I `shutdown -r now` my FreeBSD then (mysql_enable="YES" in rc.conf). MySQL works but starts to make 1GB bin files every 20 minutes again.

## APPENDIX 1

Mysql works for aimsniff and netams. I've stoped netams. And mysql stoped to produce "mysql-bin." files. So the problem is between mysql and netams presumably. But I can't find the reason yet.

There's some lines of "mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000179 | less" command when I try to read the mysql-bin. file which was created before the current one.

> 'fw-sher1# mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000179 | less
> '/*!40019 SET @@session.max_insert_delayed_threads=0*/;
> '/*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
> 'DELIMITER /*!*/;
> '# at 4
> '#130915 11:27:20 server id 1  end_log_pos 98    Start: binlog v 4, server v 5.0.81-log created 130915 11:27:20
> 'Warning: ignoring Append_block as there is no Create_file event for file_id: 1417
> 'Warning: ignoring Append_block as there is no Create_file event for file_id: 1417
> 'Warning: ignoring Append_block as there is no Create_file event for file_id: 1417
> 'Warning: ignoring Append_block as there is no Create_file event for file_id: 1417
> '# at 98
> '#130915 11:27:19 server id 1  end_log_pos 8313
> '#Append_block: file_id: 1417  block_len: 8192
> '# at 8313
> '#130915 11:27:19 server id 1  end_log_pos 16528
> '#Append_block: file_id: 1417  block_len: 8192
> '# at 16528
> '#130915 11:27:19 server id 1  end_log_pos 24743
> '#Append_block: file_id: 1417  block_len: 8192
> '# at 24743
> '#130915 11:27:19 server id 1  end_log_pos 32958
> '#Append_block: file_id: 1417  block_len: 8192
> '# at 32958
> '#130915 11:27:19 server id 1  end_log_pos 41173
> '#Append_block: file_id: 1417  block_len: 8192
> '# at 41173
> '#130915 11:27:19 server id 1  end_log_pos 82248
> '#Append_block:Warning: ignoring Append_block as there is no Create_file event for file_id: 1417
> 'Warning: ignoring Append_block as there is no Create_file event for file_id: 1417
> 'Warning: ignoring Append_block as there is no Create_file event for file_id: 1417

And so on an on and on. It doesn't make any sense for me.

What says netams.log

> File: netams.log        Line 1006126 Col 0 180576689 bytes 84%
> 13.09.2013 23:59:52.8916 data-source:1 [WARN]: Got the following ERRORS from MySQL: level = Error, code = 126, message = Incorrect key file for table './netams/monitor.MYI'; try to repair it.
> 13.09.2013 23:59:52.8916 data-source:1 [WARN]: Got the following ERRORS from MySQL: level = Error, code = 126, message = Incorrect key file for table './netams/monitor.MYI'; try to repair it.
> 13.09.2013 23:59:52.8919 data-source:1 [WARN]: Failed load data into sql for monitor try "debug storage"
> 14.09.2013 00:01:20.0461 data-source:1 [WARN]: SQL Load data: Incorrect key file for table './netams/monitor.MYI'; try to repair it
> 14.09.2013 00:01:20.0464 data-source:1 [WARN]: Got the following WARNINGS from MySQL: level = Warning, code = 1262, message =
> Row 243 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns.
> 14.09.2013 00:01:20.0464 data-source:1 [WARN]: Got the following WARNINGS from MySQL: level = Warning, code = 1262, message =
> Row 265 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns.

Comment: What software is running against the DB? Do you know what those log files are?

Comment: Obvious question, but, have you already try to check what's there actually in those log files in oder to find what's generating them?

Comment: where checking what's in the logs can be accomplished using `mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000179 | less`

Comment: Looks like database corruption in the `netams` tables? Have you tried repairing those tables?

Comment: found that it was all about netams. I've stoped netams. And mysql stoped to produce "mysql-bin." files. So the problem is between mysql and netams presumably. netams.log says things like that: 13.09.2013 23:59:52.8919 data-source:1 [WARN]: Failed load data into sql for monitor try "debug storage" 14.09.2013 00:01:20.0461 data-source:1 [WARN]: SQL Load data: Incorrect key file for table './netams/monitor.MYI'; try to repair it. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

```
14.09.2013 00:01:20.0461 data-source:1 [WARN]: SQL Load data: Incorrect key file for table './netams/monitor.MYI'; try to repair it
14.09.2013 00:01:20.0464 data-source:1 [WARN]: Got the following WARNINGS from MySQL: level = Warning, code = 1262, message = Row 243 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns.
14.09.2013 00:01:20.0464 data-source:1 [WARN]: Got the following WARNINGS from MySQL: level = Warning, code = 1262, message = Row 265 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns.
```

This error indicates that this the netams database has some corrupt tables. Note the section which says "*Incorrect key file for table './netams/monitor.MYI'; **try to repair it***".

Repairing tables can usually be done with a few commands. Repairing a table can occasionally lead to data loss, so back up the tables first. The repair can take a while depending on the size of the database-- sometimes the repair may appear to hang for 10-20 minutes, but it is actually quietly scanning for corrupt rows. Do this in a secondary window so you can keep an eye on it, and be patient.

For tips on repairing tables, check out the MySQL manual:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/repair-table.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/rebuilding-tables.html